# In Flutter in listview.builder, deleting an object always deletes the last one

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

There is such problem: I have in application `ModalBottomSheet` in which there is `ListView.builder`. In short, each row of the ListView has two input fields and delete button. But on whatever line the delete button is pressed, the last one is always deleted. Here is my code:

```
 List<Price> price = PriceUtils.getPrice();
        // *My code there*
        
child: ListView.builder(
  primary: false,
  itemCount: price.length,
  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
    return Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 45,
              width: 60,
              child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: (price[index].priceID !=-1)
                ? price[index].priceID.toString()
                : null,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(204,199,199,199))),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))))),

            const SizedBox( width: 15),

            SizedBox(
              height: 45,
              width: 100,
              child: TextFormField(
                initialValue: (price[index].priceID !=-1)
                  ? price[index].priceCount.toString()
                  : null,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(204, 199, 199,199))),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))))),

            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35 ),

            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                   price.removeAt(index);});},)
```

More precisely, the last element is removed only visually, everything in the `price` list itself is deleted correctly, that is, if you close `ModalBottomSheet` and open it again, the list is displayed correctly. But, as you understand, constantly opening and closing the widget to update the data is a solution that is too crutch and inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:
because you used ListView.builder, therefore it will list up all items from your list, and the index will be increased till rendered all of the items from your list.
That's why the index always is the last one.

If you want to delete that item that you touch. You can wrap with "GestureDetector Widget", when you touch the value of index will be changed.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          // return ListTile(
          // title: Text('Date: ${myList[index]}'),
          // // subtitle: Text('Subtitle: ${items[index].SubTitle} '),
          // );
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  items[index].Id,
              );
            },
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('Date: ${items[index].Date}'),
              subtitle: Text('Subtitle: ${items[index].SubTitle} '),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```

Q2:
When you rerendered your page, List price will be reset, and it got values from "PriceUtils.getPrice();", therefore the delete button only delete that item from "price" not from "PriceUtils.getPrice()"

Answer (score 0):

You should add ObjectKey to your widget. Like this:

````
 List<Price> price = PriceUtils.getPrice();
        // *My code there*
        
child: ListView.builder(
  primary: false,
  itemCount: price.length,
  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
    final price=price[index];
    return Column(
    /////////////////////RIGHT HERE
    key:ObjectKey(price),
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 45,
              width: 60,
              child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: (price[index].priceID !=-1)
                ? price[index].priceID.toString()
                : null,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(204,199,199,199))),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))))),

            const SizedBox( width: 15),

            SizedBox(
              height: 45,
              width: 100,
              child: TextFormField(
                initialValue: (price[index].priceID !=-1)
                  ? price[index].priceCount.toString()
                  : null,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(204, 199, 199,199))),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))))),

            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35 ),

            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                   price.removeAt(index);});},)
```
````